# Create product via install script

Tags: product, install-script

I'm attempting to create a new product via an install script, but running into some issues, more specifically when trying to save the product.

The error I'm getting is: `Call to a member function getStoreIds() on a non-object`

I've isolated the error to when the product saves (see below)

When saving the product the function `_saveAttributeValue` is called from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract`

Within this function the following line is throwing an error `$storeIds = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsite()->getStoreIds(true);`

This is because when calling `Mage::app()->getStore()` from an installer script `0` is returned instead of proper store (see: [Install script to get access to root category id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12446/install-script-to-get-access-to-root-category-id))

Is there any way around this where I can the product to save

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);`

- [What is the effect of Mage::getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/29148/69)

Comment: it solves the immediate error but then causes a `Invalid category IDs.` while saving the product since `$store->getRootCategoryId()` returns `null`

Comment: my mistake it seems that another module is causing this error, will look at it soon

Comment: thanks! the other error was being triggered by a 3rd party module extending the backend model for entity_attribute